# Problem Browser in IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a main() module with flow control and explicitly create model instances using "new IloOplModel()". Running the program in IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio (12.7) the results are not shown in the "Problem Browser". Is there any way to tell the IDE to show the results of a certain model instance in the Problem Browser?

Before switching to explicit creation of model instances, I relied on the implicit model instance (available through thisOplModel). With the implicit model instance the results are always shown in the "Problem Browser".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal.

So what you could do is either

rely on scripting to display what you need:

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooprepostprocessing.mod

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;

// Preprocessing

execute DISPLAY_BEFORE_SOLVE
{
writeln("The challenge is to bring ",nbKids," kids to the zoo.");
writeln("We can use 40 and 30 seats buses and the costs are ",costBus40," and ",costBus30);
writeln("So average cost per kid are ",costBus40/40, " and ",costBus30/30);
}

// Decision variables , the unknown

dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;

// Objective
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
// Constraints
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}

// Postprocessing

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
writeln("The minimum cost is ",costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30);
writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses and ",nbBus30," 30 seats buses ");
}
```

or write .dat in files so that you can use the problem browser with .mod and .dat without a main block

Example:

subvalue.mod

```
float maxOfx = ...;
dvar float x;

maximize x;
subject to {
  x<=maxOfx;
}

execute
{
writeln("x= ",x);
}
```

and then

main {

```
  var source = new IloOplModelSource("subvalue.mod");
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
 
 
 
  for(var k=1;k<=10;k++)
  {;
  var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
    
  var data2= new IloOplDataElements();
  data2.maxOfx=k;
  opl.addDataSource(data2);
  opl.generate();

  if (cplex.solve()) {  
     opl.postProcess();
     writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());
     writeln(".dat");
     writeln(opl.printExternalData());
    
  } else {
     writeln("No solution");
  }
 opl.end();
}  


}
```

that gives

```
x= 1
OBJ = 1
.dat
maxOfx = 1;

x= 2
OBJ = 2
.dat
maxOfx = 2;

x= 3
OBJ = 3
.dat
maxOfx = 3;

x= 4
OBJ = 4
.dat
maxOfx = 4;

x= 5
OBJ = 5
.dat
maxOfx = 5;

x= 6
OBJ = 6
.dat
maxOfx = 6;

x= 7
OBJ = 7
.dat
maxOfx = 7;

x= 8
OBJ = 8
.dat
maxOfx = 8;

x= 9
OBJ = 9
.dat
maxOfx = 9;

x= 10
OBJ = 10
.dat
maxOfx = 10;
```

Comment: I understand, I was hoping there is some way to achieve this as the Problem Browser is a comfortable tool for quick checks of the results. Anyway, thanks for your reply!